# Play Framework form with history

Tags: forms, scala, playframework-2.0

I'm working on an application using Play 2.0.4 in Scala, and one of the features I was asked to implement is to build a form that remembers all of the edit history. Basically, there should be a button next to every field that shows the details of every change, because the app users may want to rollback or use the edit history information later.

The first idea pops up in my mind is to assign a hidden div to every field that appends every change, and only shows the div when users click on the corresponding button. This doesn't sound very hard, but I feel like it may make the HTML a mess (since each user has his own record, each record has many fields). Or I could make a copy of the database and store all the changes inside, with the primary keys changed to be both the id of the form, and the edit time.

Thoughts? Am I overthinking the problem? Is there a more elegant way to store all of the edit history? We estimate that there would only be around 200 people in the company using it, so I guess I can let efficiency slide a little...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would normalize and persist the record in the database. This would allow you to have history on changes by having a history table for each section that they with to rollback.

This would allow manageability of restorations based on sets of data and significant changes can be tracked. Managing each field separately would be very cumbersome and least pragmatic.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't done much with database before, so I'm currently googling on how to normalize and persist records. Would you happen to have a link to some examples that I can follow?

Comment: [Anorm](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.1/ScalaAnorm) is a good place to start. A simple sqlite db would be enough for a small web-application.